# Cannot store [String] as binary data in Core Data

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, persistence

I'm attempting to use Core Data to store Alarm objects, each of which has a String array of notificationUuids that correspond to notifications that the alarm is responsible for. The problem is that when I save the alarm objects like this...

```
private func saveAlarm(alarmToSave: Alarm) {

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Alarm", in: managedContext)!
    let alarmMO = AlarmMO(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)

    alarmMO.setValue(alarmToSave.alarmTime, forKeyPath: "alarmTime")
    alarmMO.setValue(alarmToSave.alarmNumber, forKeyPath: "alarmNumber")
    alarmMO.setValue(alarmToSave.alarmIntervalBeginTimeDouble, forKeyPath: "startTimeInterval")
    alarmMO.setValue(alarmToSave.alarmIntervalEndTimeDouble, forKeyPath: "endTimeInterval")
    alarmMO.setValue(alarmToSave.recurrence.hashValue, forKeyPath: "recurrence")

    let arrayAsString: String = alarmToSave.notificationUuids.description
    let stringAsData = arrayAsString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16)
    alarmMO.setValue(stringAsData, forKeyPath: "notificationUuids")

    if managedContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            self.alarms.append(alarmMO)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save alarm to CoreData. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    } else {
        os_log("No changes to the context to save", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    }

}
```

and then try to load the alarms like this...

```
private func loadAlarms() {

    os_log("loadAlarms() called", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<AlarmMO>(entityName: "Alarm")

    do {
        if self.alarms.count == 0 {
            self.alarms = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            os_log("Loading %d alarms", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug, self.alarms.count)
        } else {
            os_log("Didn't need to load alarms", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch alarms. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

all of the other fields get loaded, but notificationUuids does not. Why does this method of converting a String array to binary data not work in Core Data? I've tried so many things...

- Setting the Attribute type to Transferable, Custom Class to [String],
  no Value transformer
- Setting the Attribute type to Transferable,
  Custom Class to NSArray, no Value transformer
- Setting the Attribute
  type to Transferable, Custom Class to [String], Value transformer to
  StringToDataTransformer below
- Setting the Attribute type to
  Transferable, Custom Class to [NSAttributedString], Value transformer
  to AttributedStringToDataTransformer below
- Setting the Attribute type
  to Transferable, Custom Class to [NSString], Value transformer to
  NSStringToDataTransformer below
- Setting the Attribute type to Binary Data

and nothing works. I'm desperate here. What's the issue?

Comment: Is changing your model an option? You could just attach multiple UUIDs to an `AlarmMO` entity via a one-to-many relationship. Just throwing it out there.

Comment: It's totally an option, at this point. How would I do that?

Comment: You'd just create a new entity, give it a property, specify a relationship with the parent (`AlarmMO`) and specify the relationship as one-to-many from `AlarmMO` to your UUIDs. I trust you're using git or some sort of version control. If you're not, save a backup copy of your project before you do it, as I don't want you to blow up your model.

Comment: The one-to-many relationship by @Adrian is indeed the most common way of solving this problem.  *Transformable* attributes are the second most common way.  Although database purists prefer one-to-many, in some cases transformable attributes give better performance.  But if your users have only tens or hundreds but not thousands of *ones* and *manys*, it won't matter.  I do see issues in your code.  If you decide that you want a value transformer for *array of strings* to *data*, ask for it in a comment and I can post mine which I've been using successfully for many years.

Comment: @TylerCheek I just saw Jerry's answer and that's probably the simplest way. I figured you'd tried transformable. Either way, you're going to be on the hook for book-keeping with the UUIDs, it's just a matter of where you want to do it.

Comment: Is there a tutorial or something to show me the correct way to use the Relationship model instead of the Transformable model?